# Как найти совпадение в массиве и вернуть его ключ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В общем, дело тёмное. У меня есть массив вида **ключ: значение**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
var arr1 = [];

$('select').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != 0) {
        arr1[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    }
}); 

/* получаем массив: var arr1 = [,,,,,'Россия, Москва',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'Россия, Брянск']; */
```

И формирование нового массива объектов, куда нужно занести ключ, если значение найдено в 1-ом массиве:

```html
<select id="example_select">
    <option value="0">Россия, Москва</option> 
    <option value="1">Россия, Ростов</option>
    <option value="2">Россия, Сочи</option>
    <option value="3">Россия, Брянск</option>
</select>
```

```
var arr2 = [];

$('#example_select option').each(function() {
    arr2[arr2.length] = {
        'address': $(this).text(), // Сюда попадет строка с адресом: Россия, Москва
        'id':  /* а вот здесь должен быть индекс найденного адреса, если не удалось найти, тогда 0 */
    }
});
```

**Как мне получить такой вот результат?**

```
arr2 = [
   {address: "Россия, Москва", id: "5"},
   {address: "Россия, Ростов", id: "0"},
   {address: "Россия, Сочи", id: "0"},
   {address: "Россия, Брянск", id: "21"}
]
```

Comment: массив вида `ключ: значение` — это как? Может массив объектов?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko Может, но индексы (ключи) не 0, 1, 2, а 5, 21

Comment: Это что, новый синтаксис языка? `var arr1 = [
   5: "Россия, Москва"
   21: "Россия, Брянск"
]` Я такого не знаю...

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko `arr1 = []; $('select').each(function() { if ($(this).val() != 0) { arr1[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).find('option:selected').text(); } });`

Comment: @RifmaMan скопируйте ваш массив `arr1` в консоль хрома, например, нажмите энтер и скажите, что там ответят.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko дак я как раз из консоли то и копирую

Comment: А вы все же попробуйте вставить ваш код в консоль `var arr1 = [ 5: "Россия, Москва" 21: "Россия, Брянск" ]`. Надеюсь, после этого вы поймете, что вам надо немного подкорректировать вопрос.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не надо оскорблений. Если вам понятно, что там синтаксическая ошибка, может тогда дадите правильный пример (без синтаксических ошибок и несуществующих конструкций), что у вас есть и что вам надо?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko изменил код в вопросе, такой синтаксис вам понятен недаюсь

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko посмотрите сейчас вопрос, сможете помочь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ни один из предложенных вариантов не является решением моей проблемы, сегодня еще погуглил, посидел, почесал репу, и решил задачу:

```js
var arr1 = arr1 = [,,,,,'Россия, Москва',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'Россия, Брянск'],
    arr2 = [];

$('#example_select option').each(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != 0) {
    var get_index = arr1.findIndex(item => item === $(this).text());
    arr2[arr2.length] = {
      'addres': $(this).text(),
      'id': (get_index > 0) ? get_index : 0
    }
  }
});

console.log(arr2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="example_select">
    <option value="0">Адрес не выбран</option> 
    <option value="1">Россия, Москва</option>
    <option value="2">Россия, Ростов</option>
    <option value="3">Россия, Сочи</option>
    <option value="4">Россия, Брянск</option>
</select>
```

p.s. В заголовке вопроса я просил помочь **найти индекс по заданному значению**, никто не подсказал мне про `findIndex`, вместо этого, люди начали задавать глупые вопросы и предлагать совершенно нелепые варианты будто не хотели вникать и написали на оте***сь, вместо адекватной помощи комьюнити я получил дизлайки вопроса (на то есть причины естественно, надо было сразу поработать над описанием) и не получил верного ответа, даже логически никто не понял какой результат я хотел получить, хотя всё вроде разжевал. Очень не порадовал результат в общем...

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать новый массив объектов на основе текущего при помощи `#array.map()`, а потом почистить от `undefined`.

```js
const array = [,,,,"first",,,,,,,,,,,,,"second",,,,,,,,"third"]

const mappedArray = array.map((item, index) => {
  return {
      address: item,
      id: index
    }  
}).filter(item => {
  if (typeof item !== undefined) return item
})

console.log(mappedArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Решение

Во-первых у вас это просто массив, а не "массив вида (ключ, значение)". Цифры перед значением, являются индексами, фактически массив их не содержит!

### Можно просто перебрать через `for`

```js
function arrayToObjArray(array) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    let obj = {};
    obj.id = i;
    obj.address = array[i];
    result.push(obj);
  }
  return result;
}

let someArray = ['Moscow', 'Samara', 'Perm'];

console.log(arrayToObjArray(someArray));
```

Comment: Всё может, вот код: `arr1 = [];
    $('select').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != 0) {
            arr1[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        }
    });`

Comment: @RifmaMan товарищ, это не «ключ:значение». У вас просто идёт 5 пустых элементов в массиве, потом по 5 индексу идёт «Россия, Москва», а после моря ещё пустых элементов идёт 21 индекс, под которым и идёт «Россия, Брянск”

Comment: @Kir_Antipov написав: _"есть массив вида ключ: значение:"_ я имел в виду что 0:значение1, 1:значение2

Comment: @RifmaMan обновил ответ, думаю вы найдете способ, который вам подойдет

Answer (score -1):

Если имеется в виду работа с DOM с помощью jQuery, то в колбэк each передается индекс:

```
$('#example_select option').each(function(index) {
    ...
```

То есть если есть какойто DOM

```
<select id="example_select">
    <option value="5">Россия, Москва</option> 
    <option value="21">Россия, Брянск</option>
</select>
```

То желаемый результат можно получить так:

```
var arr2 = [];

$('#example_select option').each(function(index) {
    arr2.push({
        'address': $(this).text(),
        'id':  $(this).val()
    })
});
```

На выходе получите:

```
arr2 = [
   {address: "Россия, Москва", id: "5"},
   {address: "Россия, Брянск", id: "21"}
]
```

Оставшиеся элементы, не встречающиеся в select, добавите отдельно.

Comment: Мне нужно взять текст каждого `option` и сформировав новый массив проверяя если текущий текст найден в значении 1-го массива, записать в новый по мимо текста еще и найденный ключ

Comment: `value` никак не привязывается, они просто порядковые 0, 1, 2... их взять не получится!

Comment: изменил код в ответе